# Grails add domain field as database index

Tags: database, grails, indexing, field

I'm using grails 1.2.2 and 1.3.7 in my project.
I want to add an index to the domain's table.

```
class Test {
String name
String surname

static mapping = {
name column: 'name', index: 'test_dx'
surname column: 'surname', index: 'test_dx'
}
```

}

I tried with the two version of grails and with dbCreate = "create" or dbCreate = "create-drop" or dbCreate = "update" (is the one I want to use) but no "custom index" created.

Comment: Do you want a particluar type of index, e.g. a unique index?

Comment: For the first step I need only an index, not unique.
The next step should be define some unique indexes (example : the couple of name and surname should be unique)

Answer (score 1):

Your example works for me.  If I run my app in `update` mode with a MySQL database, then I get this from the MySQL console:

```
mysql> show index from test;
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| Table | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment |
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| test  |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | id          | A         |           0 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| test  |          1 | test_dx  |            1 | name        | A         |           0 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| test  |          1 | test_dx  |            2 | surname     | A         |           0 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

What database are you using?